# Converting dataframe of size (20, 500000) to another dataframe of different size

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 20 rows and 500000 columns. Each row is a unique model consisting of 500000 numbers (columns). Therefore, we have 20 unique models. I want to convert this dataframe to a dataframe with only one column as "values", and the rows should consists of 20 * 500000 rows stacked on top of each other, such that the first 500000 rows should belong to the 500000 numbers of the first model, followed by the 500000 numbers of the second model, and so on. I used pd.melt() but that is not what I am looking for, as it does not put them in order of the models.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20, 500000)))
 #reshaped_my_df = pd.melt(my_df)
```

#Update: I used the df.stack() and it worked.

```
df_stacked = my_df.stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: you cannot have a dataframe of size `(20, 500, 000)` you need at least one element in the third dimension

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki The number of columns is 500000 (500k) not 500! The dataframe size is (20, 500000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the underlying numpy array and recreate the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20, 500000)))

reshaped_my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_df.values.T.reshape((-1, 1)), columns=['values'])
```

The `-1` in the `reshape` arguments stands for "make this axis whatever size needed to make the reshaping work". Since your code produces a dataframe that can't be easily visualized, here's a more readable example. This should clear any confusion over what reshape is doing

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a']*5, 'B':['b']*5,'C':['c']*5,})
>>> df.shape
(5, 3)
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  a  b  c
1  a  b  c
2  a  b  c
3  a  b  c
4  a  b  c

>>> reshaped = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T.reshape((-1, 1)), columns=['values'])
>>> reshaped.shape
(15, 1)
>>> reshaped
   values
0       a
1       a
2       a
3       a
4       a
5       b
6       b
7       b
8       b
9       b
10      c
11      c
12      c
13      c
14      c
```

Comment: thanks but still not what I meant. Perhaps, I didn;t explained correctly. Basically, I want to convert the exiting dataframe from the wide format (large columns) to the long format (large rows) keeping the order of the models, such that the first 500000 rows of the reshaped df be the first row of the original df

Comment: Never mind. I think I got it. Thanks! I used .stack method

Comment: If that's the case, answer your own question so other people that come across this one can have the answer. I still think this does what you need, but in any case, I'll update it with a readable example so it's clear what the output is.

Comment: Also, yes, I missed a transposition needed for this to work properly *facepalm\*